# net.tcp not working since upgrading to windows 10

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-10, net.tcp

After upgrading from windows 8.1 to windows 10,
None of the projects that have a WCF service available through net.tcp connections are able to connect.

The exception i get is:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '19:59:59.9769910'

the inner exception code is: 10054

But the exception happens right away. So it's not a time-out.

I checked IIS and everything is still configured right. (still have the right binding on the site, enabled protocols http,net.tcp)

I checked my services if net.tcp listener adapter was running and it was.

I checked windows features and saw that windows communication foundation non-http activation was turned off. so i turned it on and restarted my PC and still get that same exception.

I've waisted a total of 4 hours so far trying to get the net.tcp connection to work but i'm kind of losing hope here.

here are the windows features i've turned on:

[image]

and here are the windows services i have running:

[image]

Did anyone else run into this issue when upgrading to windows 10?

Comment: I ran into the same problem yesterday. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ChristianMyksvoll Sorry for answering so late. I've added our solution to the problem below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've managed to resolve this issue.

We were using a certificate in IIS with an old encryption method that was no longer being supported. (it was using MD5-RSA)
Now this was stil working in windows 8/8.1 but the certificate was no longer valid in windows 10, causing this behavior.

The solution was to get new certificates with better and supported encryption algorithms and set them up in IIS on my machine.

I'd also like to apologize for answering so late!

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working after hours of trial and error. I am not 100% sure if this is what actually solved my problem in the end, but give it a try:

1. Open "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. Uncheck "WCF Services" and all underlying boxes
3. Reboot computer
4. Recheck "TCP Activation", "TCP Port Sharing" under "WCF Services" (and any other activation methods you need)
5. Reboot computer

Comment: Perfect - you are the man! I also had this problem on a self hosted WCF application. I suspect a Windows Update had tinkered with the WCF settings under .Net 4.7.

Comment: PS. The error I was getting was System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL because TCP port is being used by another application

Answer (score 1):

Our services don't use IIS . We have self hosted WCF services. After checking

- Named Pipe
- Tcp Activation

they finally worked.